# System.Net.ProtocolViolationException: Bytes to be written to the stream exceed the Content-Length bytes size specified

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Using AWSSDK.dll I am trying to loop through the images in a zip file and send them to amazon S3 using the code below. The problem is I keep getting the error

```
System.Net.ProtocolViolationException
```

when I call the `fileTransferUtility.Upload()` method. The zip is posted as `HttpPostedFile` to the method which is used to create the zip file, then loop through each entry and upload.

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(postedFile.InputStream);

foreach (ZipEntry zipEntry in zipFile)
{

    if (zipEntry.Name != String.Empty)
    {
        string saveLocation = unzipBaseDir + "/" + zipEntry.Name;
        string dbLocation = "./" + Path.Combine(unzipBaseDir, zipEntry.Name).Replace(@"\", "/");

        // save the file

        TransferUtilityConfig config = new TransferUtilityConfig();
        config.MinSizeBeforePartUpload = 80740;

        TransferUtility fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(new AmazonS3Client(accessKeyID, secretAccessKeyID, RegionEndpoint.EUWest1), config);


        using (Stream fileToUpload = zipFile.GetInputStream(zipEntry))
        {

            TransferUtilityUploadRequest fileTransferUtilityRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
            {
                BucketName = existingBucketName,
                InputStream = fileToUpload,
                StorageClass = S3StorageClass.Standard,
                PartSize = fileToUpload.Length,
                Key = saveLocation,
                CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead

            };

            fileTransferUtility.Upload(fileTransferUtilityRequest);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly sure about `AmazonS3Client` but assuming it's just another `HttpWebRequest` type, you probably need to set `fileTransferUtility.ContentLength` to a value that does not exceed the size of your zip file(s)